# Rename DataMember during Serialization

Tags: datamember

I am trying to serialise a DataContract.....
  I would like to Rename the DataMember.

This is my DataContract

```
[DataContract(Name = "Sample")]
[Serializable]
public struct Sample
{

        public string CompanyName;


        public string AddressLine;

        [DataMember(Name="AddressLineRename")]
        public string AddressLine2;

        public string City; 

}
```

it is serialised to:

```
<Sample>
  <CompanyName>aaa</CompanyName> 
  <AddressLine>16 aaaa</AddressLine> 
  <AddressLine2>Unit 66</AddressLine2> 
  <City>Houston</City> 
</Sample>
```

what i need is:

```
<Sample>
  <CompanyName>aaa</CompanyName> 
  <AddressLine>16 aaaa</AddressLine> 
  <AddressLineRename>Unit 66</AddressLineRename> 
  <City>Houston</City> 
</Sample>
```

I want the "AddressLine2" to be serialised to "AddressLineRename".

```
Thanks.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved to rename the DataMember.

```
  [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "AddressLineRename", IsRequired = true)]
  [XmlElement("AddressLineRename")]
  public string AddressLine2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to implement `ISerializable` to customize the serialization process yourself.

I think the code you would need to add would look something like:

```
public Sample(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    CompanyName = info.GetString("CompanyName");
    // ...
    AddressLine2 = info.GetString("AddressLineRename");
    // ...
}

public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    info.AddValue("CompanyName", CompanyName);
    // ...
    info.AddValue("AddressLineRename", AddressLine2);
    // ...
}
```

See [the MSDN for ISerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable.aspx).

Comment: From where do i need to call the - Sample(SerializationInfo.....) and GetObjectData().......

Answer (score 0):

In my case I solved just adding the order parameter to DataMember

```
 [DataMember(Order = 2, Name = "AddressLineRename")]
 public string AddressLine2;
```

Don't know why..